# How to call a http request synchronously in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I want to call an http.post() request synchronously and after the response receive want to proceed with other code.
Or just want to hit the server but don't want to wait for the response.

Comment: Your two sentences are at odds with each other. Making a synchronous request means you **would wait** for the server yet in your second sentence, you say you **don't want to wait** :/

Comment: Your reason for executing the request in a synchronous way isn't appealing. You can very well streamline execution of certain statements in a specific order by making use of async/await, observables, promise etc. The request need not be executed in synchronous mode to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm just missing something, but that shouldn't be too hard if you're willing to ignore the response. If you're using angular, put somewhere at the top of your file:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Then, in the constructor, include:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, ...) {
   //...
}
```

Finally, in your code, just include the post request with an empty function after you get the result back:

```
this.http.post(url, requestBody, options).toPromise().then(() => {}).catch(error => {
    console.error("Error: ", error);
});
```

Hope this helps!